# Error Handling when try to access non-existent page X.html

Tags: spring, jsf-2, richfaces, http-status-code-404

I'm running an application with spring 3.2.2, hibernate 4.2.2 and JSF 2.1 (mojora) with RichFaces 4.3.2

My config is well working. I can access a page by .xhtml,.jsf,.jsp but...

The problem is at the display when you try to access a page who doesn't exist (as an example blabla.xhtml who is not created). How to handle the error ?

Thanks guys for your help.

This is the error , this will cause infinite recursion:

```
ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my web.xml :

```
  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <!-- JSF Mapping -->  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

 <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
  <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Faces ConfigPath Context --> 
  <context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name> 
      <param-value>classpath:webConfiguration/faces-config.xml</param-value> 
   </context-param> 

   <!-- Add Spring Context  -->
  <context-param>
  <param-name> contextConfigLocation </param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:webConfiguration/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

    <!-- Apache EL Faces Context --> 
    <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
   </context-param>

    <!-- Richfaces Skin Context --> 
    <context-param>
       <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
       <param-value>laguna</param-value>
    </context-param>

   <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <listener><listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class></listener>
  <listener>
  <listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
  </listener-class></listener>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the pages that does not exist, you should be getting an error-status code 404. You can handle the error codes by defining below fragment in your `web.xml`

```
 <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Well it's working if you add, what Mubin said before and you also need to erase  the line  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> in serlvlet mapping

Comment: It's strange that it apparently fixed it for you. Because, if you don't specify that, then the server-default one will be shown instead. Apparently erasing the incorrect URL pattern was the *actual* solution and not specifying a custom error page. Therefore this answer is completely wrong and should not have been accepted.

Comment: yes this is true; But i accepted the answer because i thought it was understandable with my comment. But not all.sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. Set this Mapping function in your root controller, but importat is that your sub controllers don't have any mapping with * character

Example root controller function:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/*", "/**"})
public String pageNotFound() {

    return "app/pagenotfound";
}
```

Example of mapping for sub links or sub mapping controllers

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/something", "/something/"})
```

if you decaler sub mapping controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/something", "/something/*"})
```

Then root controller will omit pageNotFound mapping function for this controller.